# Using Aggregate<> function in IMongoCollection and how it is different form .Aggregate() in MongoCollection

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am pretty new to the Mongo world. I am trying to execute a aggregate function in c# using pipeline approach. 
MongoDB Version used: **3.2**. 
C# Driver version : 2.2.4 for both mongoC# and mongoDB driver

C# Here's the code

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");

IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase("Interaction");

IMongoCollection<CollectionStructure.Interactions> collection = database.GetCollection <CollectionStructure.Interactions>("Interactions");
//IMongoCollection<CollectionStructure.Interactions> result;

var unwind = new BsonDocument
{
    {
        "$unwind",
        new BsonDocument
        {
            {"path", "$Pages" }
        }
    }
};

var group1 = new BsonDocument
{
    {
        "$group",
        new BsonDocument
        {
            {
                "_id", new BsonDocument
                {
                    {"UrlPath", "$Pages.Url.Path"},
                    {"InteractionId", "$_id"}
                }
            },
            {
                "count", new BsonDocument
                {
                    {"$sum", 1}
                }
            }
        }
    }

};
var group2 = new BsonDocument
{
    {
        "$group",
        new BsonDocument
        {
            {
                "_id", new BsonDocument
                {
                    {"UrlPath", "$_id.UrlPath"}
                }
            },
            {
                "distinctCount", new BsonDocument
                {
                    {"$sum", 1}
                }
            }
        }
    }

};

var sort = new BsonDocument
{
    {
        "$sort",
        new BsonDocument
        {
            {"distinctCount", "-1" }
        }
    }
};

AggregateArgs pipeline = new AggregateArgs(); //= new[] {unwind,group1,group2,sort};
pipeline.Pipeline = new[] { unwind, group1, group2, sort };


##error##
var result = collection.Aggregate<>(pipeline);
```

Interaction class is simply getter and setter class, code is as follows:

```
public static class CollectionStructure
{
        [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
        public class Interactions
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string contactId{ get; set; }
            public string channelId { get; set; }
            public string language { get; set; }
            public string siteName { get; set; }
            public int value { get; set; }
            public int visitPageCount { get; set; }
            public List<Pages> Pages{get; set;}
        }

        public class Pages
        {
            public string url {get; set;}
            public int visitPageIndex {get; set;}                
        }
}
```

So 2 quick questions:

1. How exactly to use Aggregate function in above scenario. Please guide me if I am doing something wrong.
2. What are these 2 separate collection MongoCollection and IMongoCollections and when to use what.

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can someone please help this newb :(

Comment: After browsing the related links i think .Aggregate() function is probably deprecated in the latest Mongo version, I am using 3.2. Also much help is not available online

Comment: add your c# class, provide driver version

Comment: Thanks for replying. Updated my question. Let me know if you need more info @profesor79

Comment: please check driver version 3.2 calls for mogo version

Comment: @profesor79: Sorry my bad. MongoDB version is 3.2 and C# driver version installed is 2.2.4 for both mongoC# and mongoDB driver. Updated the same above

Answer (score 0):

are you sure there's supposed to be `<>` there? I can't find any documentation instructing it.

Also `<T>` is usually to reference "Template" for classes, see `List<MyCustomClass>` and I have never seen it used empty before

Comment: I am not saying to keep <> empty. I just wrote above what intellisense showed me in VS and I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: you most probably want to skip the <>.

Comment: sorry but i didn't get what you are proposing here. Can you please explain?

Comment: what kind of error is the line `var result = collection.Aggregate<>(pipeline);` throwing?

I suspect that using the line `var result = collection.Aggregate(pipeline);` since I have never before seen the version you are using before (and I suspect it may be invalid syntax(currently on phone so I can't test)).